# Javascript: terminate requests that don't come from a specific path or requests that are direct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want force users to first click on some links and then go to a specific address. How can I terminate traffic sources that are direct in the second page? Or is there any way to only accept requests that are from specific a url?

Note: if there is something wrong, I want the page not to be viewable.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use the `document.referrer` property, and check weather or not the url matches the first page. Something like this, perhaps:

```
if (document.referrer !== 'http://www.google.com')
{
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';//redirect to first url
}
```

---

As Bergi pointed out in his answer: this kind of functionality is really better left to the server side. Though suggesting cookies is, as far as I'm concerned, not the ideal way of doing this, since cookies can be turned off client side, or WCS, tempered with.

Depending on which server side technology you're using, it might pay off to read up on all tools you have at your disposal to play with the request the user sends to your application, and take appropriate actions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a cookie in the first page that the user is allowed to view the second one.

Then your serverside application would check the cookies before delivering the second page, and otherwise redirect or show an error message.

You should not do such things via JavaScript (which includes the jQuery library), elsewhile everybody who disables JS could view the page.

Comment: brilliant idea thank you. but what if i do some css and javascript codding that the content only be viewale in javascript-enabled browsers? except users with no-javascript can not view contents, is there any other disadvantages with this method?

Comment: Yes, even apart from browsers that allow disabling stylesheets: You still deliver the content somehow, you just don't show it with your own methods. Of course everything depends on how secure your solution needs to be.